# Is there any way that I can create a method that might have a different call and return parameter object?

Tags: c#

I am using this type of code:

```
lock (l)
{
   try
   {
      var data = db2.Query<CardSetWithWordCount>(qry);
      return data;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      db2.Rollback();
      Debug.WriteLine(ex);
      Console.WriteLine(qry);
      throw;
   }
}
```

or another example like this:

```
lock (l)
{
   try
   {
      var data = db2.Query<CardSetDetails>(qry);
      return data;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      db2.Rollback();
      Debug.WriteLine(ex);
      Console.WriteLine(qry);
      throw;
   }
}
```

The code is exactly the same except for the different objects that are the return type of db2.Query.

As it takes many lines I would like to replace these two blocks with a single method that I call and pass in the return object and a try string. But I am not sure where to start because the object returned which is in this case:

```
  <CardSetWithWordCount>
```

could be different (such as  )for each method I would like to replace.

Is the way that I could do this in a method and if so how would I declare the parameters?

Comment: You could make use of [Generic Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods).

Comment: @TobiasTengler but OP said the implementation might be different

Comment: That code smells. It's unusual to require a code lock around a DB method.

Comment: It's one of the suggested ways of dealing with SQLite database calls on a mobile application.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I think by "different variations throughout my code" he meant that the type argument changes. It's not my fault, if his question is not clear enough. I just assumed what he's most likely after.

Comment: @Alan2 what do you mean by different variations? Different signatures or different implementations

Comment: For SQLite calls, isn't it enough to enable WAL mode for the database and then just use transactions as normal? (though I don't want to spark a full discussion about this, just something for you to look into separate from your question here)

Comment: Lasse I didn't know about WAL mode. I was just going by the numerous examples such as this although I am sure there are better examples:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt736454.aspx

Comment: I changed the question to try and explain better.  Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Fix your real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics like this:

```
T RunQuery<T>(YourDB db, string qry)
{

   lock (l)
   {
       try
       {
           T data = db.Query<T>(qry);
           return data;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          db.Rollback();
          Debug.WriteLine(ex);
          Console.WriteLine(qry);
          throw;
       }
    }
 }
```

Call it like this:

```
YourType res=RunQuery<YourType>(db2,qry);
```

pleas look hier for more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

Comment: Can you show me how I could call this also?  Thanks

Comment: RunQuery<YourType>(db,qry)

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a Type parameter as a function param, then do your `db2.Query` passing in the type.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean.